# Some .png image appears as blue circles in iOS

Tags: ios, png

## The problem

I have received four social network icons from a designer as `PNG`s. All four images are viewed on OSX without any problem.

However, when the images are used in an iOS device (I've checked iPhone 5 and 6), only the WhatsApp icon appears correctly **and the other 3 icons appear as blue circles**:

[image]

## Findings

### Original files

#### Facebook (appears as blue circle)

- URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESHEp.png
- MD5:  `9756c7557996b682fb7dfcf7483efe93` (same as my local `btn_facebook_sm.png`)
- [image: Facebook icon]

#### WhatsApp (appears correctly)

- URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEdzx.png
- MD5: `679138951ce4a25ddadb2a17538bade1` (same as my local `btn_whatsapp_sm.png`)
- [image: WhatsApp icon]

### File format

Running [exiftool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) on the Facebook icon gives the following output. As far as I can tell, this - plus the fact the file can be viewed in OSX and online in imgur - means the file is a proper `PNG`.

```
$ exiftool btn_facebook_sm.png
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.65
File Name                       : btn_facebook_sm.png
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 1430 bytes
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:12:21 16:34:58+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:12:21 16:35:26+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:12:21 18:24:17+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : PNG
MIME Type                       : image/png
Image Width                     : 42
Image Height                    : 42
Bit Depth                       : 8
Color Type                      : RGB with Alpha
Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
Filter                          : Adaptive
Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
SRGB Rendering                  : Perceptual
Image Size                      : 42x42
```

The diff between this file and the WhatsApp file gives:

```
< File Name                       : btn_whatsapp_sm.png
---
> File Name                       : btn_facebook_sm.png
4,7c4,7
< File Size                       : 1971 bytes
< File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:12:17 12:03:26+02:00
< File Access Date/Time           : 2015:12:21 18:26:01+02:00
< File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2015:12:21 18:24:17+02:00
---
> File Size                       : 1430 bytes
> File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:12:21 16:34:58+02:00
> File Access Date/Time           : 2015:12:21 18:26:50+02:00
> File Inode Change
```

This means that the files have the same properties and only differ in size, name and date.

Any idea why iOS refuses to display the file?

Comment: If those are added to UIButton, check button type and state for which the image was added

Comment: The default setting when building an iOS app is to postprocess true color, alpha shaded PNG images; they get their alpha removed and RGB info moved around. Does the same thing happen when you disable this PNG optimization?